# Keeping an object tree in sync across processes

Tags: c++, active-directory, replication, distributed-computing, transactional-replication

I have a tree of objects which needs to be kept in sync between 2 processes. The objects can be added/modified/deleted in either process and the data needs to be replicated in the other process consistently.

It's enough if the trees are loosely consistent as long as the conflict resolution is deterministic.

I have studied how Active Directory does this via Multi-master replication and how dropbox solves this problem. I prefer the AD approach because that seems to be more efficient for my problem.

I have also read about Operational Transformation and Optimistic Concurrency Control.

I have 2 questions.

1. Do you know of any other concepts that I can google for that can
   help me solve this problem?
2. Do you know of any libraries which solve this problem that I can
       study and use? I would really prefer not to reinvent the wheel and
       run into problems that were solved 20 years ago.

I feel that this is a common problem that a lot of people must have solved before me. But my google-fu is failing me.

Comment: _Do you know of any libraries which solve this problem_ Asking for libraries is, explicitly, off-topic on SO.

Comment: From my experience, there are 2 common approaches: pessimistic lock and optimistic lock. Active Directory uses optimistic approach. Also AD has some features such as LostAndFound container, which is used when one user moves some object to an OU and the other one deletes that OU at the same time. Don't know if move operation is supported in your program. Pessimistic lock is much easier to implement, however, I believe that in your case optimistic lock should be used